# How to update the CSS style in head tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p{font-size:14pt;color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="hello"> this is a p tag </p>
            <p> this is a p without class defined</p>
            <div> this is a div tag 
                <p> this is a p tag within the div</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "OriginalMail" class = "orgmail">
            <p> this is a Original Mail</p>
            <p class="hello"> this is a p tag </p>
            <p> this is a p without class defined</p>
            <div> this is a div tag 
                <p> this is a p tag within the div</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using a javascript function to restrict the style to get applied only to div with class name `orgmail`.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var OriginalMail = document.getElementById("OriginalMail");
var className = OriginalMail.className;
var selectorAppender = "div." + className +  " ";
for (var i in sheets) {
    var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
    for (var r in rules) {
        var selectorText = rules[r].selectorText;
        if(typeof selectorText !== "undefined") {
            rules[r].selectorText = selectorAppender + selectorText;
        }
    }
}
```

the style is getting applied only to the div with class name.

**But I want to modify the Style tag data also with the restriction.**

I was expecting the below line will update the data in Style Tag.

```
rules[r].selectorText = selectorAppender + selectorText;
```

Please help me to sort this issue.

Comment: why are you trying to modify the css file (stylesheet)... try to put the style you want in the element directly.

Comment: i need to modify it as i am getting the style from a another application, which i dont want to get affected to my data. if there is  any way please let me know. Adding manually is not what i want. I want to udpate the same using Javascript.

Comment: so you want to have this at the end : http://jsfiddle.net/wY864/1/

Comment: Style tag should be as you mentioned. But since you have manually added the style like that and also used my Javascript , the output got changed. it is not following the style as the style got modified again with the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Was hard ! =)

I modified your JS like so :

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var OriginalMail = document.getElementById("OriginalMail");
var className = OriginalMail.className;
var selectorAppender = "div." + className +  " ";
for (var i in sheets) {
    var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
    for (var r in rules) {
        if(typeof rules[r] === "object") {
            var selectorText = rules[r].selectorText;
            var style = rules[r].style.cssText;
            if(typeof selectorText !== "undefined") {
                sheets[i].deleteRule(rules[r]);
                var rule = selectorAppender + selectorText + " {" + style + " }";
                sheets[i].insertRule(rule,0);            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lots of properties of css rules are read-only so you've got to delete the rule and add a new CSS rule.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wY864/4/) of it.

Apolo

Comment: when i am trying to get the document.documentElement.innerHTML, still the <style> is same.p{font-size:14pt;color:red;}. when i send my html file to another application, the restriction which we brought is not getting reflected. :(

Comment: I know, and if you inspect the code, it is not being affected. But that's another (close) question...

Comment: I thought you just had to load external CSS which you can't manually edit

Comment: actually your answer helped to find a solution to my problem. What i did, i wrote a javascript function to remove all the style tag from the document and added the newly created ones.